# how to stop a spinner after select item first run function : android

Tags: android, spinner

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

fill spinner by

```
static final String[] Months = new String[] { "January", "February",
      "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
      "October", "November", "December" };

  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Months);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

for stop  spinner Run-time program

1 - code

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        protected boolean inhibit_spinner = false;


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            if (inhibit_spinner == true) {

                //////////////////go to function///////////////
            }
            inhibit_spinner = true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
    });
```

2 - code

```
spinner.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

              /////////////go to function///////////////

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }});
        }
    });
```

---

**why select "January" not run function **

January is frist item in spinner

---

**Is  spinner one item OR but selected item first the default in spinner  If the first item is selected again if the program is not first choice**
(run function after select first item spiner )
if first select item "January" not go to function(After January first option is to run the same if we choose not go to function ) ???????

Comment: Can you, please, explain yourself **in English**? because I didn't understand what are you asking.

Comment: nobody could understand this....please explain exactly what You want...and don´t use google translator..please..

Comment: **why select "January" not run function **

January is frist item in spinner

Comment: Or tell us which algorithm you used to encrypt your question...

Comment: I want the first item selected when the program is executed

Comment: you already answered it, because its first item, so onItemSelected() is NOT called, add another item to ur array "select month" ,"January",...

Comment: Do you have another way? OnClickListener  dor refresh?